# 403 - AccessDenied when listing objects on service running on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running with an IAM role attached to it.

If I run the following on the terminal of that instance it correctly lists the content of the bucket.

```
aws s3 ls --region my-region s3://my-bucket-name
```

But if I run what I think is the same code, but in Java, I get a 403

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(my-region)
        .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false))
        .withPayloadSigningEnabled(true)
        .build();
s3Client.listObjectsV2(my-bucket-name);
```

Generates the following

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied
```

Same goes for the original listObjects

```
s3Client.listObjects(TestArtefactsBucket);
```

Since I am using InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider, this should be using the same profile as used by the CLI, so therefore be using the same permissions?

I'm using com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.93 and since it was mentioned in another thread, I'm using joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7.

Version of Java is  java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm convinced the permissions are set up correctly, but I am having no luck getting access.

I should also add that I can list the bucket content running the following cli command on the EC2 instance as wel

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --region my-region --bucket my-bucket
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  I don't work with Java so I can't suggest what to verify, there... but it [seems legit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html).
  Unless aws-cli has a hard-coded key/secret and isn't using the role, I am without a useful suggestion, but this looks like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to check your IAM role [ Access Key & Secret Key ] which is being used for the API.

If [ Access Key & Secret Key ] is ok and you are facing same problem then you need to check IAM role policy, set S3 Full Access. This access permission is very much important and most of the time this permission setting solve access denied problem. Hope it will work for you.

[S3 access permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRfXp.png)

Still not working? Then check bucket policy, who can read and write objects in the bucket.

Comment: You are giving conflicting advice. Either the access key id & secret are relevant, or the instance role is, but not both.  The bucket policy should not be a factor since the credentials used by aws-cli appear to be working.

Comment: I am using InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider, so do not have or need an access key/secret, and since the CLI works, the policy is correct.